# Is there a way to call a method in a specific class when overriding in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I want to achieve the following functionality, where capital letters represent types:

```
// Recursive functions with base case omitted
Class A {
  X f1(Y y) { ... AA aa = this.f2(Z z); ... }
  AA f2(Z z) { ... X x = this.f1(Y y); ... }

Class B extends A {
  @Override
  X f1(Y y) { ... AA aa = this.f2(Z z); ... }
  @Override
  AA f2(Z z) { ... AA aa = super.f2(Z z); X x = this.f1(Y y);... }
}
```

However, when I call `new B().f2(z)` , `B::f1` is invoked inside `A::f2`. Is there some special syntax/keyword (instead of this) that allows me to always invoke `A::f1` in `A::f2`?

I know you can re-implement the same function but I want to avoid that

Comment: this is an indication that probably your *model* is not correct - why override a method if the original should be called

Comment: @user16320675 both the original and new methods are called in B::f2; the original to be called within super.f2(z) and the new one is directly called in B::f2

Comment: You could move the code of `A::f1` to another method `f3`, then make `A::f1` call `f3` directly, and `A::f2` call `f3` instead of `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with Java. If a method is overridden, calling it on a class instance will call the most-specific one. This is known as the [frage base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

C# has introduced the `new` keyword to counter this, but Java does not offer this possibility.